# AngularJS: Declaring unique variable inside interceptor

Tags: angularjs, http, interceptor

I have a need to have a variable that is unique per request inside my http interceptor.  So when the request comes in I want to set this variable to some value and read that value on the response.  The issue is that the interceptors are shared so every time a new request comes in my variable will just be overridden.

```
angular.module('app').factory('httpInterceptor', ['$q',
function($q) {
    var myInstanceVar = "";

    return {
        request: function (config) {
            myInstanceVar = Math.random();
            return config;
        },
        response: function (response) {
            console.log(myInstanceVar);
            return response || $q.when(response);
        }
    }
}
]);
```

So in this example, I would want `myInstanceVar` to be unique when I output the value in `response` but instead it just outputs the value that was generated the last request.  So if I have 3 requests the output would be `3,3,3` instead of like `5,9,3` since the last request set it to `3`.

I know I could probably just append the value to the request body and have the server return it back but I want to avoid that if possible.

I am using AngularJS 1.6.4 if that matters.

Comment: Store the variable in the config, and get it back in response.config.

Comment: @JBNizet perfect thanks!!  Please add answer and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the variable in the `config`, and get it back in `response.config`.